# Filter dates from the first day of the month to the current date

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts, chart.js

I have a chart that extracts data from an JSON API. I want to display date only from the beginning of the month to the current date.

Start date is the first day of that month and end date is the current date

I tried the following, but it is returning undefined.
I m requesting for assistance with this code.

Thank you.

Below is my code.

```
        let dates = [];
let confirmed = [];
let recovered = [];
let deaths = [];

var today = new Date();
var TodayDate = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();

var startDate = '01-04-2020'; //YYYY-MM-DD
var endDate = TodayDate; //YYYY-MM-DD

var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var dt = new Date(start);
    while (dt <= end) {
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}

var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);


fetch("https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data=> {
    data["South Africa"].forEach(o => {
      dates.filter(function() {
        o.date==dateArr;
      }).push(o.date);
      confirmed.push(o.confirmed);
      recovered.push(o.recovered);
      deaths.push(o.deaths);
    })
    new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Confirmed',
            borderColor: 'orange',
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
            fill: 'false',
            data: confirmed
          },
          {
            label: 'Recovered',
            borderColor: 'green',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            fill: 'false',
            data: recovered
          },
          {
            label: 'Deaths',
            borderColor: 'red',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            fill: 'false',
            data: deaths
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'COVID-19 / Eswatini Time Series'
        }
      }
    });
  });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives u list data from api between your expected dates

```js
var today = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 1);


var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var dt = start;
    while (dt <= end) {
        arr.push(dt.getFullYear()+'-'+(dt.getMonth()+1)+'-'+dt.getDate());
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}

var dateArr = getDateArray(firstDay, today);

getDatas("South Africa");

function getDatas(counryName){
  fetch("https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data=> {
        var categories=[];
        var confirms=[];
        var recovers=[];
        var result = data[counryName].filter(function(item) {
         
          return dateArr.includes(item.date); 
        })
        result.forEach(item=>{
           categories.push(item.date);
           confirms.push(item.confirmed);
           recovers.push(item.recovered);
        })
       
        var options = {
          type: 'line',
          data: {
            labels: categories,
            datasets: [
              {
                label: '# of Confirmed',
                data: confirms,
                borderWidth: 1
              }, 
              {
                label: '# of Recovered',
                data:recovers,
                borderWidth: 1
              }
            ]
          },
          options: {
            scales: {
              yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                  reverse: false
                }
              }]
            }
          }
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
        new Chart(ctx, options);
         console.log(result);
      });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
    <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the end date is not formatted as date and the loop (while) is not doing it correctly. The solution is **new Date(end)**

```
var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
var arr = new Array();
var dt = new Date(start);
while (dt <= new Date(end)) {
    arr.push(new Date(dt));
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
}
return arr;
```

}

and the complete code would be

```html
let dates = [];
let confirmed = [];
let recovered = [];
let deaths = [];

var today = new Date();
var TodayDate = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();

var startDate = '01-04-2020'; //YYYY-MM-DD
var endDate = TodayDate; //YYYY-MM-DD

var getDateArray = function(start, end) {
    var arr = new Array();
    var dt = new Date(start);
    while (dt <= new Date(end)) {
        arr.push(new Date(dt));
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return arr;
}

var dateArr = getDateArray(startDate, endDate);



fetch("https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data=> {
    data["South Africa"].forEach(o => {
      dates.filter(function() {
        o.date==dateArr;
      }).push(o.date);
      confirmed.push(o.confirmed);
      recovered.push(o.recovered);
      deaths.push(o.deaths);
    })
    new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Confirmed',
            borderColor: 'orange',
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
            fill: 'false',
            data: confirmed
          },
          {
            label: 'Recovered',
            borderColor: 'green',
            backgroundColor: 'green',
            fill: 'false',
            data: recovered
          },
          {
            label: 'Deaths',
            borderColor: 'red',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            fill: 'false',
            data: deaths
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'COVID-19 / Eswatini Time Series'
        }
      }
    });
  });
console.log(dateArr)
```